# Hard drive clicking after computer being hit, stopped after a few reboots, will my hard drive survive?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I managed to accidentally hit my desktop pc, and the hard drive (my data drive, I have a SSD for boot) started to click and rumble and it was really loud. I rebooted the pc a couple times, and it stopped, but I'm really worried about possibly loosing my hard drive. Do you think it will fail? As far as i'm aware, nothing has been corrupted and everything seems to work ok. There has been no decrease in speed or anything either.

SMART data:

[image]

Comment: Your disk is reporting its status as healthy.  This means the firmware has not identified any problems.  Unless you have identified an issue there is no reason not to believe the reported status by the HDD.

Comment: I assume you have backups anyway. Treat it as normal. If it fails, swap it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking is usually but not always bad.  It's a recalibration of the head alignment parameters, and if successful stops after a few 'clicks'.  If the drive is no longer making unusual noises, is performing satisfactorily, and provides a SMART report as fine as the one above, then it is probably fine.

However there may still be damage, as yet undetected, and you should test the surface of the entire disk.  You are running CrystalDisk, a 'pretty' program that provides a very nice display of the SMART attributes, but which inexplicably provides no access to the SMART drive tests built into every drive.  More complete SMART tools are Hard Disk Sentinel (recommended but not cheap), the SmartmonTools (for more technical users), and HDD Guardian (a GUI for SmartmonTools).

If you can, run a SMART extended drive test.  Otherwise, run the Windows Check Disk utility with the full surface testing option.  These are very long tests.  Check the SMART attributes again, after the tests complete.

Answer (score 2):

If it is clicking, you should expect it'll fail in the immediate future. You'll want to back up any data on it and probably replace the drive.

There's no guarantee that the drive will fail right away, but you should expect it to. http://harddriveclicking.net/ has some additional information, though most of it isn't good. It does point out that you might have a loose cable, for example, so it may be worth opening up the case and taking a look. Though you do say you have narrowed it down to the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking is always bad.

The sounds comes from the drive head doing repeated read attempts due to read failure.

Pull as much data as possible, and when it stops working, disconnect the drive, power and data, and remove from computer if possible, let it rest for couple hours, and try again.  Repeat until it fully dies.